# Facing issues while submitting application to Appstore

Tags: ios

While submitting my application to the App Store I'm facing some problems:

1. While loading IPA from Xcode it is showing "*The certificate for this server is invalid*".
2. When I try to drag Screenshots to iTunes Connect, it shows "*Your screenshot are not loaded, Try Again later*".

How can I fix this?

Comment: might be an internet connectivity issue

Comment: My Internet connectivity is good.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.  What have you searched for, for example?

Comment: and also the screenshot sizes a according to itunes guideline.Also my Certificates and Provisioning Profile are correct.

Comment: @ torjanfoe                                                                                                              I read a solution to logout the Account from other devices,but it also not work for me,  then i correct the date and time setting (a solution was given to change date and time of system to automatic) but it also not work for me

Comment: And also i tired this in different browsers (Crome,Firefox,Safari,IE) but i get the same response from iTunes connect